# finding the value of x,y in contour

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

im trying to understand this code and i just can't understand it. would help if someone can explain what exactly is the x,y int is in this code.i want to modify the x,y value  but i don't know how the coder got the value of it. what i understand is that to find a horizontal contour the Y needs to be in a range between 180-300 and if it is in that range then the x must be either x>300 or x<180 then you can conclude that the contour is in a horizontal position. i want to modify the x and y because i need to detect a different object

```
if len(cnts) > 0:
        for c in cnts:
            (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            radius = int(radius)
            cv2.circle(frame,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)

            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            
            if 180 < x < 300:
                if y > 300:
                    vert = vert +1
                elif y < 180:
                    vert = vert +1
                else:
                    vert = vert
            if 180 < y < 300:
                if x > 300:
                    horiz = horiz +1
                elif x < 180:
                    horiz = horiz +1
                else:
                    horiz = horiz
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somekind of Tuple Assignment. Try guess what is a, b, and c after assignment below.

```
lol = [[1, 2], ['a']]
(a, b), c = lol
```

Compare it with your code

```
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
```

Also take a look at this [article](https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/) about Tuple Assignment in python

Answer (score 0):

oh i got it, so the x and y is the center of the contour and the if elif else loop is to know the location of the contour on a 480x480 thanks